# Entity relationship many to many

Tags: database-design, erd

Is an association class in UML the same as an Link entity in ERD?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not strictly necessary to have an association class to model a M:M relationship.  You can just have classes with references to the two parents that would map directly to a link entity.  Semantically, an association class would limit you to one relationship between two entities.

A short blurb on association classes can be found [here.](http://etutorials.org/Programming/UML/Chapter+6.+Class+Diagrams+Advanced+Concepts/Association+Class/)